# TortoiseSvn Merge followed by Create Patch does not include new files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge, patch

I am doing a Merge in TortoiseSvn, which modifies some files, deletes some, and adds some.  Next I am doing a Create Patch to create a patch file with these changes.  The problem is that the resulting patch file includes only the modifications and deletions, not the adds.

I have discovered a workaround.  If I revert the adds and then do an explicit Add of those files in TortoiseSVN, then do a Patch, it picks up everything, including the Adds.

Is there a way to avoid this workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is a know bug in Subversion and it is not an issue with TortoiseSvn. It doesn't look like it will be fixed in Subversion 1.6.x because they are redoing the patch/diff system in version 1.7. So it appears you will need to continue using your workaround until version 1.7, which will hopefully have this issue fixed.

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2451115

Comment: Sorry if I commenting on old topic, but is this issue solved in current tortoise svn version?